# Putting Controls at ToolBar- Stuck

Tags: mfc, toolbar, walkthrough

I have been staring at this documentation for 5 hours now. I simply cant connect the steps. If you guys can enlighten me of the stuff.

Here is the site:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/bb983718(VS.110).aspx

So my problem are the following:
-at number 5, it asked me to "Set these parameters as follows:", it didnt even mention anything about where? Where to implement the constructor, and why are we using CMFCToolbarComboBoxButton? when it already asked me at step 4 to derive a clas called CFindComboButton. Shouldnt I be making a contstructor for that one instead?

-at number 4(sorry about the non organized numbering of problems), what I did is use the add class (not the class wizard), and then I picked MFC Class. I then enter the supposedly CFindComboButton and Base class as CMFCToolBarComboBoxButton. Did I do something wrong on this one? Do I have to do anything for the ID ID_EDIT_FIND_COMBO?

-When I register the ID_EDIT_FIND_COMBO at the String Table, I dont exactly know what I did. Did I just register an id for future implementation? or is it something else?

-So I cant do step 5, I skipped to step 6.  All it ask me is to look for the CreateCombo method athe the override section of properties at CFindComboButton. Well I can only find 3 override. None of them are CreateCombo method. Well from there, you can tell that I'm lost.

I'm a noob at mfc so you might wanna take that in consideration.

Answer (score 1):

Even though your question is a bit jump-led up, let me try and answer so that it works for you.

1. Create two class - one derived from CComboBox (call it CFindComboBox) and another from CMFCToolBarComboBoxButton (call it CFindComboBoxButton). First class will implement the Combobox that will be shown when you click the drop down button in the toolbar. This drop down button is implemented by CFindComboBoxButton. Hope this is clear.
2. Now define the constructor for the CFindComboBoxButton as CFindComboBoxButton(UNIT nID, int nImage, DWORD dwStyles) using three parameters as explained below:

   - Command ID of the button which will be ID_EDIT_FIND_COMBO (or anything you want to define it as). This will get defined in the String Table. Just add a new entry in String Table with ID_EDIT_FIND_COMBO as ID and a placeholder string. Don't omit the string value else the ID will not get defined. The string value can be anything as it wont be used anywhere.
   - Second parameter will just be a call to CCommandManager::GetCmdImage(ID_EDIT_FIND). This will return the default image used to show the drop down for combobox. In case you want to use your own custom image you can create one and instead pass the ID of that.
   - Third parameter is the styles you want to use. They are defined at http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/7h63bxbe(v=vs.110).aspx but you can use the default value (CBS_DROPDOWNLIST) to start with.
3. Override the CreateCombo method of CMFCToolBarComboBoxButton and add its implementation to CFindComboBoxButton. In this method create and return a pointer to CFindComboBox (CComboBox derived class).

I hope this clears all the confusion and you should be on your way to have a custom Combobox embedded inside a toolbar.

Comment: I have to work at the moment, so I'll check this out later. A VERY BIG THANKS.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the VisualStudioDemo Sample:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983983%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

you can find the CFindComboButton implementation there